# Mysql - How to query 2 tables?

Tags: mysql

I've got a problem with a query with 2 tables

> Table A
>   id (key), name
>
> Table B
>   id, a_id (foreign key), language

In the first table you can find a lot of people and in the second languages they can speak. My problem now is, that I want to find all the people that can speak English and German (not one of them but both!) for example.
Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Please update your question with the code that you've attempted.

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

this should work, assuming your language table looks something like this
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bgk0rjo8g86rfz5/Screenshot%202014-08-11%2022.20.55.png

```
SELECT a.*
FROM b
JOIN a ON a.id = b.user_id
WHERE b.language = 'German'
OR b.language = 'English'
GROUP BY b.user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```